# Calculation using weights

Tags: stata

I have a data frame which is shown below (Except `Price2` variable):

```
+------+-----------+----------+-------+------+-------------+
| Name |    Day    |   Time   | Price | Size |   Price2    |
+------+-----------+----------+-------+------+-------------+
| A    | 24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     1 |    3 | 0.333333333 |
| A    | 24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     4 |    4 | 1.777777778 |
| A    | 24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     3 |    2 | 0.666666667 |
| A    | 24-Mar-08 | 11:03:12 |     1 |    4 |         0.8 |
| A    | 24-Mar-08 | 11:03:12 |     4 |    1 |         0.8 |
| A    | 25-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     3 |    4 |           2 |
| A    | 25-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     8 |    2 | 2.666666667 |
| A    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:13:59 |     3 |    2 | 0.428571429 |
| A    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:13:59 |     2 |    4 | 0.571428571 |
| A    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:13:59 |     5 |    5 | 1.785714286 |
| A    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:13:59 |     3 |    3 | 0.642857143 |
| A    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:59:01 |     1 |    5 |           1 |
| B    | 24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     3 |    6 |    2.571429 |
| B    | 24-Mar-08 | 10:30:01 |     4 |    1 |    0.571428 |
| B    | 24-Mar-08 | 11:30:01 |     3 |    2 |           2 |
| B    | 24-Mar-08 | 11:30:01 |     5 |    1 |    1.666667 |
| B    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:30:01 |     7 |    3 | 1.909090909 |
| B    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:30:01 |     4 |    6 | 2.181818182 |
| B    | 25-Mar-08 | 11:30:01 |     2 |    2 | 0.363636364 |
| B    | 25-Mar-08 | 12:00:00 |     6 |    2 |           6 |
+------+-----------+----------+-------+------+-------------+
```

I want to calculate `Price2` in Stata, which is `Price` multiplied by `Size` and divided by the sum of `Size` for each second.

Comment: You are expected to try code and provide a reproducible example. Your data example needs surgery before it will run.

Comment: The example is corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is similar to that of @Andrey Ampilogov, and like him I don't see where all your results come from.

```
clear 
input str1 Name str9 (Day Time) Price Size   Price2    
 A     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      1     3  0.333333333 
 A     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      4     4  1.777777778 
 A     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      3     2  0.666666667 
 A     24-Mar-08  "11:03:12"      1     4          0.8 
 A     24-Mar-08  "11:03:12"      4     1          0.8 
 A     25-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      3     4            2 
 A     25-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      8     2  2.666666667 
 A     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"      3     2  0.428571429 
 A     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"      2     4  0.571428571 
 A     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"      5     5  1.785714286 
 A     25-Mar-08  "11:13:59"      3     3  0.642857143 
 A     25-Mar-08  "11:59:01"      1     5            1 
 B     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      3     6          1.8 
 B     24-Mar-08  "10:30:01"      4     1          0.4 
 B     24-Mar-08  "11:30:01"      3     2          0.6 
 B     24-Mar-08  "11:30:01"      5     1          0.5 
 B     25-Mar-08  "11:30:01"      7     3  1.909090909 
 B     25-Mar-08  "11:30:01"      4     6  2.181818182 
 B     25-Mar-08  "11:30:01"      2     2  0.363636364 
 B     25-Mar-08  "12:00:00"      6     2            6 
end 


egen den = total(Size), by(Name Day Time)  
gen wanted = (Price * Size)/den
list, sepby(Name Day Time) 


     +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | Name         Day       Time   Price   Size     Price2   den     wanted |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |    A   24-Mar-08   10:30:01       1      3   .3333333     9   .3333333 |
  2. |    A   24-Mar-08   10:30:01       4      4   1.777778     9   1.777778 |
  3. |    A   24-Mar-08   10:30:01       3      2   .6666667     9   .6666667 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |    A   24-Mar-08   11:03:12       1      4         .8     5         .8 |
  5. |    A   24-Mar-08   11:03:12       4      1         .8     5         .8 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |    A   25-Mar-08   10:30:01       3      4          2     6          2 |
  7. |    A   25-Mar-08   10:30:01       8      2   2.666667     6   2.666667 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  8. |    A   25-Mar-08   11:13:59       3      2   .4285714    14   .4285714 |
  9. |    A   25-Mar-08   11:13:59       2      4   .5714286    14   .5714286 |
 10. |    A   25-Mar-08   11:13:59       5      5   1.785714    14   1.785714 |
 11. |    A   25-Mar-08   11:13:59       3      3   .6428571    14   .6428571 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 12. |    A   25-Mar-08   11:59:01       1      5          1     5          1 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 13. |    B   24-Mar-08   10:30:01       3      6        1.8     7   2.571429 |
 14. |    B   24-Mar-08   10:30:01       4      1         .4     7   .5714286 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 15. |    B   24-Mar-08   11:30:01       3      2         .6     3          2 |
 16. |    B   24-Mar-08   11:30:01       5      1         .5     3   1.666667 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 17. |    B   25-Mar-08   11:30:01       7      3   1.909091    11   1.909091 |
 18. |    B   25-Mar-08   11:30:01       4      6   2.181818    11   2.181818 |
 19. |    B   25-Mar-08   11:30:01       2      2   .3636364    11   .3636364 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 20. |    B   25-Mar-08   12:00:00       6      2          6     2          6 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

At first, generate a sum of size for each group of `Name` - `Day` - `Time`. Then do the rest of the math - multiply the size by the price and divide by the sum of the sizes:

`bys Name Day Time: egen sumPrice = total(Size)
 gen Price2 = Price * Size / sumPrice`

And also check a group of `Name="B"`, `Day = "24-Mar-08"`, `Time = "10:30:01"`. The `Price2` from your example and re-calculated `Price2` do not match. Other values match.